# Laravel 8 Mail Notifications

Tags: laravel, email, templates, notifications, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8, and my Client asks to be able to modify the mailables content.

I need to show the different notification templates, and let the users add text, action buttons, etc.

I'm thinking on building a DB structure to store the different fields with the corresponding order, but I'm not sure if it is possible to apply that on the toMail method.

For example: a NotificationTemplate Model that hasMany NotificationField (this can have type and content).

And then try to use it as a query builder:

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $fields = NotificationTemplate::where('name', 'example')->fields;
    
    $mail =  (new MailMessage);

    foreach($fields as $field){
        if($field->$type = 'line'){
            $mail->line($field->content);
        }
    }

    return $mail;
}
```

Is this possible? Or is there another way to allow the admins of a Laravel 8 app to modify the Mail notificiation message from the frontend?

Thanks, Hernán.

Comment: It might be worth looking at https://laravel-news.com/maileclipse-laravel-mail-editor-package

Comment: Hallo, thanks for the advice. I´ll research how they have managed to edit the Mails.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give the admin a textarea where he can customize the content of email.

I use this package [armincms/option](https://github.com/armincms/option) to stock the content and in your template email you can use `option()->content`